# using links in react-i8next

Tags: reactjs, react-router, translation, i18next

I was learning react through online sources, and I'm unable to find the solution for my problem-

suppose I have a json file -

```
"test":"This is a test file, contact at {{email}}"
```

and currently i use it as -

```
const [t] = useTranslation();

<div>t('test',{{email}})<div>
```

suppose  I want to change the colour of the email text only, how do I do that?
 I researched online, and read the Transcomponent documentation, but I'm unable to understand how to implement it.

Comment: I think you should search for CSS styling guides and how to use it within react

Comment: What link are you talking about? Please specify..

Comment: Thanks @BernardoMarques !, I tried that approach but unable to get CSS reflect. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @StarLord The link i'm talking about is email value that i pass to `t`, i want it to be of a different color

Comment: @StarLord is right, you'd need to call an anchor tag for it to be a link, your calling only a `div`

Comment: @StarLord I do not want it to be clickable, i just want the colour of the email to be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to exclude the `{{email}}` placeholder from the translated text.

So this would be the i18n part:

```
{
  "test": "This is a test file, contact at"
}
```

And this would be the React part:

```js
const { t } = useTranslation();

return (
  <div>
    {t("test")} <span style={{color: "hotpink"}}>{email}</span>
  </div>
);
```

There are a lot of variations for what you are trying to do (e.g. using external stylesheet, CSS classes, and so on), but this would be a straight-forward approach.

Comment: This is great and simple!! Thankyou.What are the other variation using CSS? can you please provide me references

Comment: You can, for example, use class names instead of the inline styling, like so: ```<span className="emailAddress">{email}</span>```

And style the span.emailAddress class in an external .css file.

Comment: If you want to keep it simple, though, there is no need for all of these variations, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle that using a `css` file, for that you need to import it to your `react` component file:

```js
import './styles.css';
```

For this to work you should create a `style.css` file on the same folder/directory of your `react` file, after that you should set a `css` rule:

#### style.css

```css
a {
  color: hotpink;
}
```

Comment: How would the `a` tag provide the appropriate css? I'm nowhere specifying it under `<a></a>`